# Remote Desktop from Mac to Ubuntu stops working when I change rooms

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, macbook, remote-access

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, so forgive the noob.

I have this odd situation when trying to remote desktop from my macbook to three separate mini pcs which all have Ubuntu 22.04.

I set them up in my living room all plugged into the router with ethernet, via a switch. They're all working perfectly.

I stand next to them with my macbook which is connected to my house wifi and i can remote desktop in to each one, no issues at all.

I carry my laptop to the other end of my house, still on the same wifi network, initiate the remote desktop again and none of them will connect any more. I just get a message on the macbook saying *"Connection failed to “192.168.1.XX”. Unable to communicate with “192.168.1.XX”. Make sure the remote computer is available and the firewall is not blocking screen sharing."*

My set up is a netgear orbi router with two satellites. When I stand in my living room the macbook is connecting to the nearest wifi point, which is also the router the ubuntu machines are connected to. When I move to the other room there are two hops across orbi satellites. The only thing I can think of is that maybe there's something on the network disrupting the remote desktop session and preventing a log in?

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about to try and make it more clear:

[image]

Any ideas? it's really frustrating. For what it's worth, I can still samba share folders with the ubtuntu machines without any issues, and ssh works fine across the board as well. It just seems it's remote desktop that really upsets everything.

Edit -  the IPs of the three servers are 192.168.1.44 / 192.168.1.64 / 192.168.1.49 and my macbook is 192.168.1.200. they all have static IPs

the IP addresses of all 4 devices stay the same wherever I am in the house. The dhcp is handled by the router and all those device IPs are reserved.  I have a couple of other mac minis on the network acting as servers and i can remote desktop into those without issue. And again, samba & ssh work fine to every machine on the network including the ubuntu servers. So it doesn't feel like subnets are the issue? disclaimer: i know next to nothing though

Comment: Please remove all the comments and put that info into the question where it belongs. Comments are only for someone trying to help you to ask for more info.